# Find() not understood

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have two collections questions and answers. I have the questions _id in the Answers collection. This is verified because I also have the Houston package that lets me see all my collections and data.

This works as expected. I verified the data is in the answers collection field questionId.

```
Questions.findOne(Session.get('question_id'));
```

This finds no data?
I have seen some examples like this so can only assume syntax is correct..?
I'm expecting a cursor of all answer records that match.

```
Answers.find( {questionId: Session.get('question_id')} );
```

This is in a template.events.

```
Meteor.call("addQuestion",questionText,function(error, question_id){
    if (error) {
      alert("Server could not save your question at this time.");
      Session.set('question_id',""); 
      Session.set('adding_answers',false); 
    } else {  
      Session.set('question_id',question_id); // Save the question _id
      Session.set('adding_answers',true); // Causes template newAnswers to be displayed
      template.find('.inputQuestion').value = ""; // Clear prior question value
    }  
  });
```

Comment: is question_id a variable?  if so, could you include the code for how it's defined?

Comment: Do you mind creating a sample of your code on [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com) so we can help you to troubleshoot it?

Comment: question_id is a session variable. I added example above.

Answer (score 0):

Well first, on my opinion don't make a `Meteor.call`, just for an inset, better do like this.

```
Question.insert({questionText:questionText},function(error, question_id){
    if (!error) {
        Session.set('question_id',this._id); // Save the question _id
       Answers.insert({questionId:question_id})
      Session.set('adding_answers',true); // Causes template newAnswers to be displayed
      template.find('.inputQuestion').value = ""; // Clear prior question value
    } else {  
      alert("Well i know this is kinda weird, but.. something wrong happened");
    }  
  });
```

Of course, with the corrects allow/deny.

Now. why the findOne, dont work.

And now the answers find will look like this.

```
  Tracker.autorun(function(){
             var findAnswers = Answers.find({question:Session.get('question_id')}) 
     console.log(findAnswers);
     }
```

So with that it should work.

Note: if you want to keep the `Meteor.call`, just copy paste the `findOne`

Comment: Questions.findOne({_id:Session.get('question_id')}); does work frind. The issue seems to be Answers.find( {questionId: Session.get('question_id')} );.

Comment: check the update, on the code example, i didn't see where you make the insert to answers, but i think the most correct its to place it on the `(!err) callback`.

Answer (score 0):

There might be something wrong on another portion of your code. 
You should be able to use `Answers.find({question_id: Session.get('question_id')});`. I created a sample on Meteorpad for you: [Link](http://meteorpad.com/pad/QN92h3y3P3exsFg82/Questions%20&%20Answers)

Check for typos on your code. Some possible mistakes:

- Are you sure the `questionId` field is on the Answers collection?
- Are you sure the field name is `questionId` and not `question_id`as you used on the Session?